# Checkbox: what value store in database?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, checkbox, backend

I'm developing an app with Laravel. I've a form with a checkbox input and I know that the checkbox input by default sends value `on` and if it's unchecked it sends nothing.

So I'm asking, what value I have to store in database if it's checked and what if it's unchecked?